# Using value_counts to find unique values across combination of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have been trying to get a count on multiple columns using value_counts. Right now, I have it working on one column, but not multiple.

EDIT: I needed a count of unique IDs previously, hence the count on 'id', but now I want a count of the services under 'id'. I'm editing the data below to more accurately explain the situation.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'id': [1, 1, 2, 3, 3], 'service': [3, 3, 4, 2, 3], 'name': ['Joe', 'Joe', 'Bob', 'Val', 'Val']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['count'] = df['id'].map(df['id'].value_counts())
```

If I try

```
df['count'] = df['id'].map(df['id']['service'].value_counts())
```

I get a KeyError on service.

If I try

```
df['count'] = df['id']['service'].map(df['id'].value_counts())
```

I get the same error.

I'm hoping to get something along the lines of:

```
id service   1 , 3: 2
id service   2 , 4: 1  
id service   3 , 2: 1  
id service   3 , 3: 1
```

Am I using the wrong function?

Comment: What is that you want to achieve?Can you show the expected output?

Comment: `df['service'].map(df['service'].value_counts())` Not sure this is what you need

Comment: It would be good to know your expected output

Comment: I didn't ask my question very well, but I've edited it to hopefully be more clear.

Comment: Why not `df.groupby(['id', 'service']).size()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of ways. Either use `groupby` and use `count`, or create a tuple column and apply `value_counts`.

Both methods provide results that can be indexed via tuples.

**Setup**

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'id': [1, 2, 1], 'service': [3, 4, 3], 'name': ['Joe', 'Bob', 'Mark']}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

**Groupby method**

As suggested by @Dark:

```
res = df.groupby(['id', 'service']).count()

#             name
# id service      
# 1  3           2
# 2  4           1
```

**Tuple column method**

```
df['id_service'] = list(zip(df.id, df.service))
res = df['id_service'].value_counts()

# (1, 3)    2
# (2, 4)    1
# Name: id_service, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Well I doubt you need that many things to get the output. Groupby will make it easy `df['new'] = df.groupby(['id','service']).transform('count')`

Comment: @Dark, in terms of complexity, doesn't `groupby` need O(n log n) ?

Comment: I din't think about complexity. Since there was mapping earlier I thought of a simple transformation. Its just a easier and simple code.